# Reassign a signal to itself on a process

Tags: signals, vhdl

I am developing a simple counter with an enable signal in VHDL, the question is if it is correct to reassign a signal to its previous value like for the output_reg signal.
Extra question: is it necessary to put the signals in the sensitivity list? I think not because in this case we have a sequential process.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;

entity counter is
    generic (
        NBit : positive := 8
    );
    port (
        en: in std_logic; 
        rst,clk : in std_logic;
        overflow: out std_logic;
        o: out std_logic_vector( NBit-1 downto 0 )
    );
end counter;

-- when en = '1' it counts the clock cycles, otherwise the counting is freezed
-- set overflow to 1 when max_val is reached

architecture beh of counter is
signal output_reg : std_logic_vector (NBit-1 downto 0);
constant max_val  : std_logic_vector (NBit-1 downto 0) := (others => '1');
begin
    counter_output_reg: process(clk, rst)
    begin
        if(rst = '1') then 
            output_reg <= (others => '0');
            overflow <= '0';
        elsif((rising_edge(clk)) AND en='1') then 
        
            if (unsigned(output_reg) = unsigned(max_val)) then
                output_reg <= (others => '0');
                overflow <= '1';
            else
                output_reg <= output_reg + 1;
            end if;
                
        else
            output_reg <= output_reg;
        end if;
    end process counter_output_reg;
    
    -- mapping the output
    o <= output_reg; -- when output_reg change this thing change.
end beh;
```

Comment: It's totally unnecessary here.

Comment: Note that you didn't assign `overflow` to itself but you don't mention it in your question. Anyway, if you don't assign a signal it keeps its value. So assigning it its own value does the same, it is completely useless. And as you have here a synchronous process that models registers it's fine. Not assigning them simply means that they don't sample a new value. That's a kind of implicit _enable_. In a combinatorial process it would be a problem because the synthesizer would infer latches to keep the values, usually not what you want.

Comment: The only reason that I can think of to do this is... documentation, to make super clear that the register does not sample a new value in this branch of the control path.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I didn't mention overflow because it is an output port and not a signal, I cannot make an assignment to an output port. Maybe I could define a signal for overflow and then assign it in the same way as output_reg but it was not necessary I think. I agree with the rest of your answer.

Comment: Well, VHDL 2008 is already 14 years old and, even if some tools still don't fully support it, most of them support at least the reading of output ports. Simply use the right option of your tool (`--std=08`, `-2008`...) and benefit from many interesting improvements.

Answer (score 1):

The comments point out that the statement is not necessary, but the structure that you've ended up with is actually not desirable at all. You've essentially got:

```
process(clk, rst)
begin
  if(rst = '1') then 
    output_reg <= (others => '0');
  elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then
    output_reg <= output_reg + 1;
  else
    -- Last branch
    output_reg <= output_reg;
  end if;
end process;
```

The last branch is active when `rst` is not asserted and there is not a rising edge on `clk`. If you need to synthesise the process, there isn't any real hardware that can detect 'absence of rising edge'. In this case, since your assignment in this branch does nothing, maybe the tool will work this out, but in general I would avoid this structure as it invites others (or future you) to put other code in this branch, which then might not work.